# Python Spark - Escaping quotes in parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

My parquet file is derived from CSV in which so some of the cells are escaped. Eg: This is a value

```
"a , ""Hello"" c"
```

I want this to be read by parquet as

```
a , "Hello" c
```

I am trying to escape quotes from the parquet file while reading.
If I were reading a CSV, I can do it in the following way

```
df = spark.read.option('quote', '"').
                 option('escape', '"').csv("./temp.csv")
```

However, we don't have a similar thing for parquet files. I've read parquet both using options and without options

```
>>> dfP = spark.read.parquet("./temp.parquet")
>>> dfP.show()
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|             _c3|_c4|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  A|  B|  C|               D|  E|
|  1|  2|3,4|"a, ""HEllo"" c"|  5|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+

>>> dfP = spark.read.option('quote', '"').
      option('escape', '"').parquet("./temp.parquet")
>>> dfP.show()
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|             _c3|_c4|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  A|  B|  C|               D|  E|
|  1|  2|3,4|"a, ""HEllo"" c"|  5|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
```

I want the D column to be read as 'a, "Hello" c'.
Is there any way to make it work?

The input parquet is converted from a CSV file which is

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,"3,4","a, ""HEllo"" c",5
```

EDIT: Parquet is already generated. I cannot change the way parquet is being generated. I've to use the parquet I got and try to escape.

Comment: Hows parquet file created from CSV? using spark-csv read as csv and write as parquet?

Comment: Are you doing this ? spark.read.option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").csv("data.csv").write.parquet("temp.parquet"). This works for me

Comment: Parquet is already generated by someone else. I cannot change the parquet format. I've just mentioned it to give more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is only one option for parquet files. And it is for compression. Other options like 'quote', 'delimiter', 'escape' are for csv files. So they don't work for parquet files.

I tried to simulate your case and I think that best solution for this case is using functions. Firstly I created a csv file and put it to HDFS

```
[ali@aliyesilli ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /test/exCsv/test.csv
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,"3,4","a, ""HEllo"" c",5
```

Then I read it as a csv file and save it again as a parquet file

```
>>> df = spark.read.csv('hdfs://localhost:8020/test/exCsv',header=True)
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  A|  B|  C|               D|  E|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  1|  2|3,4|"a, ""HEllo"" c"|  5|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+

>>> df.write.parquet('hdfs://localhost:8020/test/exPar')
```

When I tried to read the parguet file, D column is including double quotation as you mentioned

```
>>> spark.read.parquet('hdfs://localhost:8020/test/exPar').show()
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  A|  B|  C|               D|  E|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
|  1|  2|3,4|"a, ""HEllo"" c"|  5|
+---+---+---+----------------+---+
```

Then I defined a function which is called strip and use it with regexp_replace function to create string something you want to see

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as func
>>> strip=func.udf(lambda x: x.strip('"'))
>>>
>>> spark.read.parquet('hdfs://localhost:8020/test/exPar').withColumn('D', func.regexp_replace(strip('D'), '""', '"')).show()
+---+---+---+------------+---+
|  A|  B|  C|           D|  E|
+---+---+---+------------+---+
|  1|  2|3,4|a, "HEllo" c|  5|
+---+---+---+------------+---+
```

Maybe there are another different solutions but in this case I think you should use an udf or sql functions